# ChefSpec - Stub method inside resource

Tags: ruby, rspec, chef-infra, chefspec

Is there a way to stub a method call with a test value?  For example, I want get_folder_name to return 'test' during my ChefSpec test

```
directory 'Log_Folder' do
    def get_folder_name
      'c:\temp\folder'
    end

    action :create
    path get_folder_name
end
```

Tried this but it doesn't replace the value.

```
before do
  allow_any_instance_of(Chef::Resource).to receive(:get_folder_name).and_return('test')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is probably that because the method is declared in-line like that, it keeps overwriting the stub. You could try `allow_any_instance_of(Chef::Resource::Directory)` or similar, but I would probably move this logic to a custom resource where it can be stubbed slightly more naturally.

Comment: Adding "::Directory" didn't work.  What if I move the method to the recipe instead of the resource?  I tried using allow_any_instance_of(Chef::Recipe) but that didn't work either.